Prevent abuse of Firebase Phone Auth
Recently, an unknown attacker started abusing our iOS app's Firebase Phone auth by spamming requests to Google.cloud.identitytoolkit.v1.AuthenticationService.SendVerificationCode with various phone numbers from different IPs. Conseqently, our app loses approximately 200 USD every day.
To my astonishment, Firebase shows itself as totally helpless against the attacks.
AppCheck seems to do nothing (every option that could be enabled was already enabled), and moreover, there is no basic thing as a quota of requests per IP address for the SendVerificationCode calls.
The "support" is useless also. It continues to repeat the cytes from online docs without trying to investigate the case.
I thought that "Blocking functions" could help, but I've laughed loud after knowing that they called after the SMS was already send, so they can't prevent abuse in my case.
So, the main question to the community is: Guys, how do you protect your Firebase Phone Auth from abuse? Or is it better to leave it alone and migrate to any alternative service?
Regards,

Have you enabled verification via silent notifications.  It is likely that your api key has leaked.  What restrictions have you put on the api key?

@Paulw11 Firebase API keys do not "leak".  They are necessarily public information once the hosted app goes live.  Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public

Yes, ok.  Leak is the wrong term. But, if the attacker is able to use the API key to launch phone auth requests from outside of the app then the apikey probably isn't correctly restricted

@Paulw11 I suppose Firebase AppCheck should handle cases like this or not?

Yes, if your api key is limited to your app bundle and app check is configured.   You also need to follow the instructions I linked to to ensure that your app can receive silent notifications in order to verify that your app is the source of the request.  If requests are being made from arbitrary locations then something isn't restricted correctly.  And yes, you may want to consider whether phone auth is worth the hassle given it is relatively insecure

@Paulw11, I believe "phone auth is relatively insecure" is the wrong term for lack of basic abuse protection like quota per IP.
Every security option found in Firebase was enabled. Taking into account that a normal user can still log in, I consider we've done well on our side.

I am not referring to abuse.  I am using Google's own words for the process as a whole - Anyone who has access to the phone or can see messages sent to the phone can log in. Also, someone could register and then get a new phone number.  Now they can't log in.  And then their number goes back into the pool and it is later assigned to someone else.  Now that person goes to use your app and gets someone else's account.

@Paulw11, thanks for your suggestions and for sharing your thoughts. They are much appreciated. I get that phone auth is far from the ideal authentication method, but unfortunately, our app needs the user's phone number for its functionality.

@Orange Have you configured an SMS region policy with an allowlist or blocklist yet? The Metrics Explorer can be used to discover which regions have low verification rates.

@samthecodingman, restricting SMS region policy is not a solution. The attacker changes the country codes every time (modifying the script is not such a big deal), and second, we have valid users across the world.

@Orange Have the support team managed to provide you with metrics regarding what verification method is being used to verify the devices sending the requests to the SendVerificationCode endpoint? This would be split between "XX% iosReceipt, XX% recaptchaToken, XX% safetyNetToken" (annoyingly app check tokens don't seem to be supported on this endpoint). I suspect that the distribution is heavily skewed to reCAPTCHA where they are obtaining your site key via the recaptchaParams endpoint, feeding it to a solver service, then using the result to spoof a real device.

@samthecodingman, thanks for your attention. The support team provided me with nothing, just references to how-to's I could find myself.
Can I obtain the metrics on my own? If yes, please guide me. I don't see the option to split it by verification method; I see it only by credential, API, or response code.

@DougStevenson Do you know if this is/would be possible from the user side using something like Metrics Explorer? or is it an implementation detail that only the engineering team would be able to isolate?

Generate a new API key, implement tight restrictions, use that one instead and add your own secret key in every functions that call that API, log the calls to a cloud based database and compare the usage of the new api key, with the ones from firebase report. That way at the very least you get to pinpoint whether the leak is from your source or from firebase

Thanks for the hint. It is definitely worth a try.
